# Is it possible to combine a bootstrap collapsible list menu with jQuery UI menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Currently, I have a jQuery UI menu as follows:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="leftsidemenu">
            <ul id="leftmenu" class="menu">
                <li data-target="tabstransmgmt" class="listitem">Transaction Management</li>
                <li data-target="tabsasprocessing" class="listitem">Configure Processing</li>

                <!-- below item should only be visible to admins-->
                <li data-target="tabsuseradmin" class="listitem">User Administration</li>
           <li data-target="tabsabout" class="listitem">About</li>
            </ul>


    </div>
```

**JS**

`$("#leftmenu").menu();`

**JS Functions For Each Click of menu item:**

```
$('#leftmenu>li').on('click', function(){

    var mvar = 0;
    $(".tabui").each(function() {

        $(this).hide();
    });


    $(".listitem").each(function() {

        $(this).css("background", "transparent");
    });

    $(this).css("background-color", "#C8C8C8");

    var targetId = $(this).data('target');
     var target = $(document.getElementById(targetId));
     target.show();



});
$(function showTab(target) {

    if (document.getElementById(target)) {
        document.getElementById(target).show();
    }
 });

$(function hideTab(target) {

    if (document.getElementById(target))
    {
        document.getElementById(target).hide();
    }

 });
```

So the basic  end result of all this is a UI which has a list of menus on the left side, and depending on which is clicked, the right side gets populated with the appropriate tabbed panels, and the selected menu item remains highlighted with the dark gray background, to indicate it was selected. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Now my goal is to include collapsible submenus on the left menu, and in my research, I couldn't find that jQueryUI supports this, however, I found that bootstrap provides something like this, called collapsible list group:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    
      <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">User Administration</a>
     </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
     </ul>
     
      </div>
      
      <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">About</a>
     </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
     </ul>
      </div>
      
    </div>
     </div>
```

I don't know where to start or if it is even possible to combine this with my jQuery UI menu, so I am looking for any ideas on how this can be achieved if possible. The goal is to have the parent menu open a default tabbed panel on the right side, and the sub menus will have other tabs different from the default tabs of its parent.

Or is there another alternative to achieve this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, all I needed to do was put the jQueryUI menu into the bootstrap menu, and things worked fine:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"
     integrity="sha256-DI6NdAhhFRnO2k51mumYeDShet3I8AKCQf/tf7ARNhI="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    
      <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">User Administration</a>
     </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div id="leftsidemenu">
        <ul id="leftmenu" class="menu">
            <li data-target="tabstransmgmt" class="listitem">Transaction Management</li>
            <li data-target="tabsasprocessing" class="listitem">Configure Processing</li>

            <!-- below item should only be visible to admins-->
            <li data-target="tabsuseradmin" class="listitem">User Administration</li>
       <li data-target="tabsabout" class="listitem">About</li>
        </ul>


</div>
     
      </div>
        <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">About</a>
     </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">One</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Two</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">Three</li>
     </ul>
      </div>
      
      
    </div>
     </div>
<script>
$(document ).ready(function() {


$("#leftmenu").menu();
  });
</script>
```